# Why is my Ranked Binary search tree implementation is so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, binary-search-tree

So I wrote a Ranked self-balancing Binary Search Tree instead of using std::set. I was expecting it to work faster for getting rank of elements, but it seems to take more time than using std::set and iterating through to find rank. Is there any way to speed it up?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

struct treeNode{
    int data;      
    int leftsize;  //for finding rank
    int height;    //for balancing during insertions and deletions

    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;

    treeNode()
    :data(NAN), leftsize(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}

    treeNode(int val, int lsize, int ht)
    :data(val), leftsize(lsize), height(ht), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}
};

int height(treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return 0;
    
    return node->height;
}

int getBalance(treeNode* node)
{
    if(node==nullptr)
        return 0;
    
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}


int parseLeftSub(treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return 0;
    int cnt = 1;
    cnt += parseLeftSub(node->left);
    cnt += parseLeftSub(node->right);
    
    return cnt;
}

void printNode(treeNode* node)
{
    if(node ==  nullptr)
        return;
    
    printNode(node->left);
    std::cout << node->data << "  " << node->leftsize << std::endl;
    printNode(node->right);
}

treeNode* createNode(int val)
{
    treeNode* node = new treeNode(val, 1, 1);
    return node;
}

treeNode* createTree(std::vector<int>& a, int start, int end)
{
    if(start>end)
        return nullptr;

    int mid = (start + end)/2;

    treeNode* node = createNode(a[mid]);
    node->left = createTree(a, start, mid-1);
    node->right = createTree(a, mid+1, end);

    node->leftsize += parseLeftSub(node->left);

    return node;
}

treeNode* rightRotate(treeNode* y)  
{  
    treeNode* x = y->left;
    treeNode* T2 = x->right;
  
    // Perform rotation  
    x->right = y;  
    y->left = T2;  
  
    // Update heights  
    y->height = std::max(height(y->left), 
                    height(y->right)) + 1;  
    x->height = std::max(height(x->left), 
                    height(x->right)) + 1;  
  
    // Return new root
    y->leftsize = parseLeftSub(y->left) + 1;
    return x;  
}

treeNode* leftRotate(treeNode* x)  
{  
    treeNode* y = x->right;  
    treeNode* T2 = y->left;  
  
    // Perform rotation  
    y->left = x;  
    x->right = T2;  
  
    // Update heights  
    x->height = std::max(height(x->left),     
                    height(x->right)) + 1;  
    y->height = std::max(height(y->left),  
                    height(y->right)) + 1;  
  
    // Return new root
    y->leftsize = parseLeftSub(y->left) + 1; 
    return y;  
}  

treeNode* insertNode(int val, treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return createNode(val);

    if(val < node->data)
        node->left = insertNode(val, node->left);
    else if(val > node->data)
        node->right = insertNode(val, node->right);
    else
        return node;
    
    node->height = 1 + std::max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
    node->leftsize = parseLeftSub(node->left) + 1;
    
    int balance = getBalance(node);

    if(balance > 1 && val < node->left->data)
        return rightRotate(node);
    
    else if(balance < -1 && val > node->right->data)
        return leftRotate(node);
    
    else if(balance > 1 && val > node->left->data)
    {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }
    
    else if(balance < -1 && val < node->right->data)
    {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    return node;
}

treeNode* searchNode(int val, treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    
    treeNode* foundNode = nullptr;
    if(val == node->data)
        return node;

    else if(val < node->data)
        foundNode = searchNode(val, node->left);
    else
        foundNode = searchNode(val, node->right);
    
    return foundNode;
}

treeNode* findLowerBound(int val, treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    
    if(val == node->data)
        return node;

    else if(val>node->data)
    {
        return(findLowerBound(val, node->right));
    }

    treeNode* temp = findLowerBound(val, node->left);
    if(temp != nullptr && temp->data >= val)
        return temp;
    else
        return node; 
}

treeNode* findUpperBound(int val, treeNode* node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    
    if(val == node->data)
        return node;

    else if(val<node->data)
    {
        return(findUpperBound(val, node->left));
    }

    treeNode* temp = findUpperBound(val, node->right);
    if(temp != nullptr && temp->data <= val)
        return temp;
    else
        return node; 
}

treeNode* findMinNode(treeNode* node)
{
    if(node->left == nullptr)
        return node;
    return (findMinNode(node->left));
}

treeNode* deleteNode(int val, treeNode*& node)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    if(node->data > val)
        node->left = deleteNode(val, node->left);
    else if(node->data < val)
        node->right = deleteNode(val, node->right);
    else
    {
        if(node->left==nullptr && node->right==nullptr)
        {
            delete node;
            node = nullptr;
        }

        else if(node->left==nullptr)
        {
            treeNode* temp = node;
            node = node->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(node->right==nullptr)
        {
            treeNode* temp = node;
            node = node->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            treeNode* temp = findMinNode(node->right);
            node->data  = temp->data;
            node->right = deleteNode(temp->data, node->right);
        }
    }    

    if (node == NULL)  
        return node;
    
    node->leftsize = parseLeftSub(node->left) + 1;
    node->height = 1 + std::max(height(node->left),  
                           height(node->right));  

    int balance = getBalance(node);  
  
    if (balance > 1 &&  
        getBalance(node->left) >= 0)  
        return rightRotate(node);  
  
    if (balance > 1 &&  
        getBalance(node->left) < 0)  
    {  
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);  
        return rightRotate(node);  
    }  

    if (balance < -1 &&  
        getBalance(node->right) <= 0)  
        return leftRotate(node);  

    if (balance < -1 &&  
        getBalance(node->right) > 0)  
    {  
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);  
        return leftRotate(node);  
    }  
    
    return node;
}

int findRank(int val, treeNode* node)
{
    int rank = node->leftsize;
    if(node==nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if(val<node->data)
    {
        rank -= node->leftsize;
        rank += findRank(val, node->left);
    }
    else if(val>node->data)
    {
        rank += findRank(val, node->right);
    }

    return rank;    
}
```

I know its quite a lot. Also can any other stl containers be used to find rank, insert and delete efficiently

Comment: Haven't looked at the code much yet, but `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is utterly <expletive deleted>ing your build times.  There's no need to include the entire C++ standard library for this job. You need something like three headers, not thousands.

Comment: Sticking a `NAN` into an `int` doesn't strike me as a good idea. I don't think it's causing any visible harm, but I wouldn't trust the state of `data` after the default constructor.

Comment: Your `parseLeftSub` traverses the entire subtree at that node. It's possible to update the "left size" in constant time, by looking only at the immediate neighbours. (This is a requirement for maintaining the logarithmic complexity of operations.)

Comment: The performance of tree-based structures (as well as many others) is relative. Some are better for fast insertion, some for fast deletion, some for fast access. AFAIK, no data structure is the fastest for everything. So can you add a main with a small benchmark code to clearly define what you want to measure (and agree on the metric)?

Comment: @user4581301 Just changed the #includes and removed the constructors. Very minute improvement in performance, but still slow.

@molbdnilo `parseLeftSub` is used during insertions, deletions and while balancing, so as the tree structure is changing the subtree must be parsed to get the new `leftsize`. Relying on the immediate neighbour will not update the value properly.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am trying to use this Ranked BST as the events datastructure for Line Sweep algorithm, where I am trying to find out the no of intersections of vertical and horizontal line segments. The test case fails due to time out, but that particular test case dosen't fail if I use a std::set. Later another test case times out if I use std::set, so I thought of writing this container

Comment: No, @user4581301 is right about `leftsize`: when a node has been inserted in the sub-tree the `leftsize` fields of the subtree should have been updated too, which mean you can use them to know the new `leftsize` value. Balancing can be done only with local modifications too. To be more clear: only the ancestors of a newly inserted node should be updated if we ignore the balancing. Balancing should not change the complexity of the insertion as it could be done after it and only on the nodes of the edited branch. I advise you to give a look to [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Comment: Note also that a tree implementation like AVL or Red-Black are a quite expensive data structures. Sorted arrays are much faster/simpler for few elements (eg. less than 15) and B-tree faster for a large amount of elements. Those two are also more compact in memory.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, I thought again and removed parseLeftSub. And yes that was the reason the complexity wasn't logarithmic. Jérôme Richard  Thank you too, for pointing out my misjudgement.

Comment: Moreover the Max time used fell from 2.56 millisecs to 0.10 millisecs. (I dont know the exact unit) . Am amazed by this and I clearly see the superiorty of choosing BST.